# Couldn't avoid NullReferenceException in Action Filter (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, action-filter

I'm writing an action filter for setting `LastAccessDate` user property. On retrieving user's record from DB, i'm getting `NullReferenceException`. How to get rid of this exception? Here is my Action Filter:

```
public class LogActivity : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var resultContext = await next();

            var id = int.Parse(resultContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
            var repo = resultContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserRepo>();
            
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            // var user = await repo.GetRespondent(id);

            var user= repo.GetRespondent(id).Result; <========= Here Exception occurs

            if (user != null)
            {
                user.LastAccessDate = DateTime.Now;
                await repo.SaveAll();
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is my `UserRepo` repository's get method:

```
public async Task<User> GetRespondent(int id)
        {
             var user= await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
            if (user!= null)
                 return user

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
var user= repo.GetRespondent(id).Result; <========= Here Exception occurs
```

with

```
var user = await repo.GetRespondent(id);
```

Comment: I have tested it but got same exception

Comment: Is the repo null at this statement ? If yes, then you need to check if you're GetService is setup correctly

Comment: You should be using GetRequiredService. This method fails if the service cannot be instantiated and you will get to know instantly. GetService on the other hand will not tell you if it fails and you will need to do Null checks before you use the instance - in this case you repo is probably not being instantiated which you will notice if you switch to GetRequiredService

Comment: Yes repo was actually null. using GetRequiredService now says Service is not registered but i'm registering it in Startup.cs using `services.AddScoped<IUserRepo, UserRepo>();`

Comment: Okay I was using `resultContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserRepo>()` where `UserRepo` should be `IUserRepo`. Thankyou for you help.